# WPF Combobox changing wrong fields in datatable

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox

I'm working on a VB.net & WPF project, which contains a datatable with a combobox. When the cell with the combobox isn't being editted, the selected combobox value is being displayed in a textblock.

On my own PC (Windows 10), everything works fine. However, as soon as I transfer the program to the PC of my client (Windows 7), the comboboxes start to behave incorrectly. When I change the value of one of the comboboxes, other fields change as well. The weirdest thing is that sometimes all other fields in the same column change, and other times only a few. But in the end only the changed combobox field should change.

I recorded 2 small clips (see the URL below) in which you can see how it should work (the top one) vs. how it is working on Windows 7 (the bottom one).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DBcW.jpg

This is the XAML code of the text/combobox:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Reason for Write Off" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=reason, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Name="ComboBox1" ItemsSource="{StaticResource ComboBoxReasonItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=reason, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ></ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the ItemSynchronization? You are using the same static ItemsSource for all "rows" and synchronize them. check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem?view=netframework-4.7.2 and try to remove it.
The seemingly "random" behaviour is most likely because of the datagrid's Virtualization

Comment: @themightylc this was indeed the problem. The weird thing though is that it only happend on Windows 7 and not on Windows 10. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Glad I could help. I have posted my advice as an answer, if you have the time, you may accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Property `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` is set to true, it synchronizes the selected Item in the ComboBox with the ItemsSource. As all "rows" bind to the same static List, and they all sync up, this behaviour is expected.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem?view=netframework-4.7.2.)